# Vim does not execute plugins in editor, only in application

Tags: windows, vim, nerdtree

I am on windows 10. I set up my files like this.

~/.vimrc

```html
set nocp
source ~/vimfiles/autoload/pathogen.vim "location of my pathogen.vim
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

autocmd vimenter * NERDTree

syntax on

filetype plugin indent on
```

~/vimfiles/autoload/pathogen.vim

~/vimfiles/bundle/nerdtree

When I open via the desktop application Vim I can use the :NerdTree command okay, I can also use other pluings, but when I open the vim editor from git bash or cmd.

One thing to note is that I do not need the autocmd vimenter command to run :NERDTree in Vim application, but it errors when I try to open :NerdTree from the vim editor.

Any ideas for what I can check?

Comment: Your question is too poorly worded and formatted for anyone to give you more than generic tips regarding the general context of your problem. Fix it if you actually want some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, Vim expects your `vimrc` to be in *either* of these two locations:

- `%UserProfile%\_vimrc` (note that it's a `_`, not a `.`),
- `%UserProfile%\vimfiles\vimrc` (note that there's no `_` or `.` anymore).

The latter is generally recommended because it allows you to keep all your Vim stuff under a single, easy to move around, directory.

---

Once you have moved your `vimrc` to a correct location you can remove the first line which is completely useless as Vim sets the `nocompatible` option itself when it finds a `vimrc` at an expected location.

See `:help vimrc` and `:help 'nocompatible'`.

---

The second line is also useless because lines 3 and 4 use a feature called "autoloading" through which Vim already knows where to find those functions.

See `:help autoload`.